# Find src of an html, and insert that src into a newly created object

Tags: jquery, events, get, copy, fetch

The title mostly explains it. I have an img element. Double clicking it creates a new img element, but i want it to use the same src as the one i've double clicked. Hence, i want this single script to work for multiple different images. I'm not sure how to fetch the src, and insert it.

As well, the copies will have a class added to them that identifies them as a copy. I've tried to create a script to delete elements with class 'copy' when double clicked, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question here is a valid solution to your problem.

> Double clicking it creates a new img
>   element, but i want it to use the same
>   src as the one i've double clicked....As well, the copies will have a class added to them that identifies them as a copy.

```
$("img:not(.copy)").live("dblclick", function(){
    $("body").append($(this).clone().addClass("copy"));
});
```

This is using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) however could be changed to use [`.dblclick()`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) depending if the originals are not loaded dynamically. The `img:not(.copy)` will only target images that do not have the class of copy. The current element `this` (which is the `<img/>`) is than [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and added a class of copy.

> I've tried to create a script to
>   delete elements with class 'copy' when
>   double clicked, but it's not working.

```
$("img.copy").live("dblclick", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

To target the reverse, we simply want to target images with the class of `.copy` and simply call [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the element.  Note `.live()` (or `.delegate()`) is required here since the elements are generated after dom ready.

[**Code example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/9yJeB/)

Comment: I'm trying to implement your code, but for some reason its not working. I've pasted a simple toggle class script into my html header, within a script tag, and even that's not working.

Comment: @Jason, make sure everything is in a document ready, `$(function(){});`

Comment: Whoops, i had no jquery.js file linked to the document. I forgot i was working on a different page than the one that already does. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The source for the clone element is identified by a class name. However, i have multiple instances of this container div called by this class. When the clone is made, a clone is made for each instance of this container class. Is there a way to isolate the copy to this particular container?

Comment: That should be possible, if you could make a demo in jsfiddle, might be able to offer some additional assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Your code would be something along the lines of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //need to use live to have newly generated images bind to the click
 $('img').live('click', function(){ 
  $('body').append('<img src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" />');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `.attr()` method of jquery

```
.attr('src', value); // to set value
.attr('src');        // to get value


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("img").bind("click", function() {

          $(document.createElement("img"))
        .attr({ src: $(this).attr('src'); }).appendTo(this.parent());;
    });
});
```